# Create an intermediate CA with openssl

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I am attempting to create an intermediate CA for testing and development purposes.
I have successfully created my `root CA` with which I have issued a `client certificate` following this [tutorial](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/), but I cannot create an `intermediate CA`, issued by `my root CA`, that can issue the `client certificate`.

To create the intermediate CA I'm using this openssl command:

```
openssl x509 -req -in domainCA.csr -CA myCA.pem -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out domainCA.crt -days 1024 -sha256 -extfile domainCA.ext
```

The domainCA.ext file contains this:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE
keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign, digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
```

The certificate window show this problem (_DomainCA is the intermediate CA):

[image]
[image]

Comment: That (config and command) **looks valid to me**. That display looks like Windows; is it? Is it the popup for just opening a file containing the cert or in certmgr, or from some software that is trying to rely on the cert like IE, Edge, Outlook? You could try the approach(es) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203109/validate-certificate-chain-with-powershell or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761249/x509certificate2-verify-returns-false-always to see if you get a more helpful error message.

Comment: Try installing the **_DomainCA** certificate into your Windows **Trusted Intermediate Certification Authorities** store.  You can probably exclude: nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Yes, was the Windows screenshot of the popup of the certificate, not in certmgr, just certificate.
leeharvey1: Thank you, I miss this step... now it's all correct.